# How to write JUnit test case for @Query method

Tags: unit-testing, spring-data-jpa, junit4

I know how to write `JUnit` test case for `findBySInvestigatorName(String SInvestigatorName)` such method. But I want to know how to write test case for `@Query` method. Can any one please tell me how to write test case for following method?

```
@Repository
public interface InvestigatorRepository extends JpaRepository<Investigator, Integer> {

    @Query("select new map(invest.sInvestigatorName as sInvestigatorName)"
            + " from Investigator invest where invest.nInstId=60")
    Set<Investigator> findSinvestigatorName();

}
```

**I tried like this**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class TestInvestigatorRepository {

    @Autowired
    public TestEntityManager testEm;

    @Autowired
    InvestigatorRepository investRepo;

    @Test
    public void testFindSinvestigatorName() {

        Investigator invest = new Investigator();
        invest.setsInvestigatorName("abc");
        invest.setnInstId(60);

        Investigator saveInDb = testEm.merge(invest);

       Set<Investigator> getFromDb = investRepo.findSinvestigatorName();

      assertEquals(saveInDb.getsInvestigatorName(), getFromDb);

    }
```

**Test Failure**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<abc> but was:<[{sInvestigatorName=abc}]>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test is almost fine, except that you compare a `String` with a `Set<Investigator>`.

Change your assertion to

```
assertEquals(saveInDb.getsInvestigatorName(), getFromDb.iterator().next().getsInvestigatorName());
```

*Note: You might want to look into AssertJ. It allows you to write much nicer assertions for collections*

Comment: not working I am getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.spacestudy.model.Investigator

Comment: sounds like your test works just fine and is telling you that your repository does not return a `Set<Investigator>`s but a `Set<HashMap>`.

Comment: but it's return type is `Set<Investigator>` not `Set<HashMap>`

Comment: That means something in the conversion from what gets returned from the database to the desired return type goes wrong. But that really is a different question.